# In Grails, how do I test @Secured annotations in automated tests?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, spring-security, integration-testing

I have a controller method that I'm annotating like so:

```
@Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN'])
def save() {
    ... // code ommitted
}
```

I'm trying to write a unit test to verify that only the admin user can hit the URL:

```
def "Only the admin user should be able to invoke save"() {
    given:
    def user = createNonAdminUser() // let's pretend this method exists
    controller.springSecurityService = Mock(SpringSecurityService)
    controller.springSecurityService.currentUser >> user

    when:
    controller.save()

    then:
    view ==~ 'accessdenied'
}
```

However, the view returned is the `save` view and not the access denied view. It looks like it's bypassing the `@Secured` annotation altogether. Is there a way to test `@Secured` annotations from either a unit test or integration test?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SpringSecurityUtils.doWithAuth('superuser') {
    controller.save()
}
```

http://greybeardedgeek.net/2011/05/13/testing-grails-controllers-with-spock/

Answer (score 0):

You would need to login the user before calling controller save if you are not doing it already in `createNonAdminUser()`.

`SpringSecurityUtils.reauthenticate username, password`

Possibly related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507854/how-to-authenticate-user-against-spring-security-in-unit-tests) question.